# Chrome Extension: How to get data out?

Tags: google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension, file-access

I appreciate this question may appear broad. But it is because I am looking anywhere and everywhere for a possible solution to do something very simple.

The goal is from a web page opened in Chrome, to scan the DOM, extract specific elements and save them silently in **some way that I can then access**.

There is no intention for any of this to be published as an app or extension, it is simply me wanting to access my own rendered browser data and extract and store this data on my own computer. For this reason, I am currently finding Chrome's exhaustive sandboxing security frustrating and irrelevant to say the least.

I have a working Chrome Extension which extracts all of the data I want, has a list of 5 strings that I want to save and that's as far as I have gotten.

I have looked into these areas:

- Existing NPAPI Plugins (could not get [npapi file io](https://code.google.com/p/npapi-file-io/) to work).
- Creating my own NPAPI Plugin - seems like a huge overhead and learning exercise simply to get external access to 5 strings
- Every aspect of Chrome extension (and even App) apis (particularly their localstorage which is not accessible from outside the extension)

Any other thoughts?

I realise there is a solution through creating my own NPAPI plugin but I would like to believe that there is another approach that allows me to link a constructed DOM with my local system. I am open to any other option? (I have considered a Linux purely bash approach but I need to generate the DOM as though it was in my browser).

I just want to be able to access specifically extracted parts of a DOM on my local system, not write an entirely new C++ plugin to facilitate this very basic feature.

Comment: You want this information to be stored in local file io? If so NPAPI Plug in is only possible option, if you want it to be stored else where like local file system etc it is possible with chrome extensions

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Do you need a browser at all? It seems that you want to parse a DOM tree, then serialize it. Have a look at http://phantomjs.org/. If this option does not suit, and you desperately need a quickly working solution, write a small server in the language of your preference, and use a protocol (eg HTTP) to send data back and forth.

Comment: @RobW, I don't necessarily need a browser. The problem is the page I am accessing needs flash to run and is signed into first - which Chrome automoatically does. I think I'll look into your server idea. Even though it still sounds like overkill in my eyes (just to save a file... haha), it is looking like the best option

Comment: You are right. Local Storage is not accessible outside extension. Currently, I am working on an extension where the DOM details are stored in the indexDB of background page (The idea is to make the data persistent).  Now my plan is to provide a way to download this data. The work is still in progress.